# Mapped Tables Column Type Conversion on Apply UnApply

Tags: scala, slick

I have a Class ReportTemplate that has the field *filter*. Now ReportTemplateRow is the db class representing ReportTemplate. What I want is to have filter of type JsonAST.JValue in ReportTemplate, but String in ReportTemplateRow (when saved on db).... I want the conversion between ReportTemplate and ReportTemplateRow to happen automatically.

The below code is working, but obviously without any conversion...so instead I have to explicitly convert ReportTemplate to ReportTemplateResponse everytime I need to use ReportTemplate in my code...

I know I should overide the apply and unapply methods, but I am not being able to figure out exactly how...I've googled the issue with different keyword, but couldn't find conclusive answers.

```
case class ReportTemplate(id: Long, reportId: Long, name: String, group : Option[String], filter : String, created : DateTime)

class ReportTemplateRow(tag: Tag) extends Table[ReportTemplate](tag, "ReportTemplate"){
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def reportId = column[Long]("reportId")
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def group = column[Option[String]]("group")
  def filter = column[String]("filter", O.SqlType("text"))
  def created = column[DateTime]("created",O.SqlType("timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))

  def * = (id, reportId, name, group, filter, created) <> (ReportTemplate.tupled, ReportTemplate.unapply)
```

What I expect to have is something similar to the following:

```
case class ReportTemplate(id: Long, reportId: Long, name: String, group : Option[String], filter : JsonAST.JValue, created : DateTime)
object ReportTemplate {
  def unapply(r: ReportTemplate) : (Long, Long, String, Option[String], String, DateTime) = (r.id, r.name, r.group, JsonAST.compactRender(r.filter), r.created)
  def apply(id: Long, reportId: Long, name: String, group : Option[String], filter : String, created : DateTime) : ReportTemplate =
    ReportTemplate(id, reportId, name, group, parse(filter), created)
}

class ReportTemplateRow(tag: Tag) extends Table[ReportTemplate](tag, "ReportTemplate"){
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def reportId = column[Long]("reportId")
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def group = column[Option[String]]("group")
  def filter = column[String]("filter", O.SqlType("text"))
  def created = column[DateTime]("created",O.SqlType("timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))

  def * = (id, reportId, name, group, filter, created) <> (ReportTemplate.apply, ReportTemplate.unapply)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you have a text database column (`filter`) which you want to work with in terms of a different type in Scala.

Slick provides a column-based mechanism for this as `MappedColumnType.base`.

The idea is:

- in your database row class, you type your column as you want to use it (JSON in this case).
- you also provide an implicit conversion from that type (JSON) to the database type (String).

The details are in [the manual](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/userdefined.html) and also in Essential Slick tutorial, [chapter 5](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/userdefined.html).

In outline, for your case it may be something along the lines of this (nb: won't compile; just a sketch):

```
implicit val filterTypeMapping =
    MappedColumnType.base[Json, String](
      json => json.toString, // or however you do this for the JSON you're using
      txt  => json.parse(txt).get /// or however you do this in the JSON lib you're using
    )
```

With that in scope, Slick will "learn" how to convert your JSON data type to a database-friendly type.

Note that your parsing of text to JSON may fail. That could be a run-time error, or you might choose to represent it as a different type such as `Try[Json]` or similar.